# Measuring the change in a categorical variable across two time points (data is dependent so chi2 does not hold) with some 0 cells

Tags: categorical-data, repeated-measures

I am trying to see if there are differences in how comfortable people are in adopting children at two time points. Their responses are ordinal ex. very likely, somewhat likely, not at all likely etc. Normally I would do chi2 but the data is not independent (how important is this assumption - does it make the chi2 value worthless, or just reduce the power?)

Ex. A crosstab of the variable  at time 1 and time 2 generates a matrix such as this where 1 = very likely, 4 = not at all likely etc.

```
       VL.   SL.   NVL.  NAAL.

VL      42    6     5     7

SL      0    28    20     10

NVL     2     9    47     21

NAAL    1     1     5     100
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Are you testing the hypothesis that people don't change their minds over time? Or are you interested in comparing the distributions across time?

Comment: Thank you for responding. My goal is to see if an intervention led individuals to change their minds, and more specifically, if they are more likely to adopt.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Ryan. Could you please tell us the sense in which the data are not independent?  The relevant concept would be independence *between subjects,* not between responses, so in what sense are the responses of one subject associated with those of any other subject?  Concerning the title, could you explain why you are concerned about a zero cell? That's not a problem for a chi-squared analysis.

Comment: (Note, though, that a chi-squared analysis addresses a rather uninteresting question in this context.  It will tell you whether the second set of responses is independent of the first, but that doesn't go very far in helping you with your stated research objective.)

Comment: @whuber It seems I am mistaken, I thought there had to be independence between responses and since they are the same person, I thought they were not independent. I have read that chi2 does not do well with 0 cells and to use fisher's exact test instead with small cells, I tried in stata, but it would not run as it would exceed memory.

Comment: That's a common confusion: the rule (of thumb) is that the *expected count under the null hypothesis* in *most* cells should be $5$ or greater.  That's the case for all your cells.  Fisher's Exact Test is not a perfect replacement -- its null hypothesis is subtly different.  The solution to the problem of having many cells with low expected counts is to estimate the p-value through simulation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an ordered probit model. Here's an example in Stata of what that can yield:

[image]

Here each color corresponds to an answer on the second survey. The x-axis gives the initial response. The y-axis shows the probability. The points above each x value add up to 100%.

For example, let's take someone who responded with NAAL on the first survey. The model says he has a 92% percent of saying that again. The probability of switching to VL the second time is only 1.5%. The fact that the CIs don't overlap means the differences are also statistically significant. When CIs overlap a lot, the estimates are not statistically distinguishable. If there is scant overlap, you can still reject the null that they are the same. When in doubt, do the hypothesis test instead of using your eyeballs.

You see a very similar pattern for folks who said VL initially. They are most likely to give the same answer at 58%.

In the middle of the scale, the differences are less stark. For example, folks with SL and NVL are ~40% likely to respond with NVL the second time.

Overall, this graph is consistent with no change in preferences over time.

---

**Code and Output:**

```
. clear

. input str4(r1 r2) noobs

            r1         r2      noobs
  1. "VL"   "VL"  42
  2. "VL"   "SL"   6 
  3. "VL"   "NVL"  5
  4. "VL"   "NAAL"  7
  5. "SL"   "VL"   0 
  6. "SL"   "SL"  28 
  7. "SL"   "NVL" 20 
  8. "SL"   "NAAL" 10
  9. "NVL"  "VL"  2 
 10. "NVL"  "SL"  9
 11. "NVL"  "NVL"  47
 12. "NVL"  "NAAL" 21
 13. "NAAL" "VL"  1
 14. "NAAL" "SL"  1
 15. "NAAL" "NVL" 5
 16. "NAAL" "NAAL" 100
 17. end

. sencode r1, replace

. sencode r2, replace

. tab r1 r2 [fweight = noobs], chi2

           |                     r2
        r1 |        VL         SL        NVL       NAAL |     Total
-----------+--------------------------------------------+----------
        VL |        42          6          5          7 |        60 
        SL |         0         28         20         10 |        58 
       NVL |         2          9         47         21 |        79 
      NAAL |         1          1          5        100 |       107 
-----------+--------------------------------------------+----------
     Total |        45         44         77        138 |       304 

          Pearson chi2(9) = 363.6680   Pr = 0.000

. /* Dynamic Ordered Probit Model */
. oprobit r2 i.r1 [fweight = noobs]

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -385.73824  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood =  -263.0663  
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -260.63228  
Iteration 3:   log likelihood = -260.62633  
Iteration 4:   log likelihood = -260.62633  

Ordered probit regression                               Number of obs =    304
                                                        LR chi2(3)    = 250.22
                                                        Prob > chi2   = 0.0000
Log likelihood = -260.62633                             Pseudo R2     = 0.3243

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          r2 | Coefficient  Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
          r1 |
         SL  |    1.34081   .2159196     6.21   0.000     .9176159    1.764005
        NVL  |   1.797881   .2125711     8.46   0.000      1.38125    2.214513
       NAAL  |   3.591913   .2586678    13.89   0.000     3.084933    4.098893
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       /cut1 |   .1954002   .1605833                     -.1193372    .5101376
       /cut2 |   1.063496   .1779466                      .7147267    1.412265
       /cut3 |   2.159035   .1914654                       1.78377    2.534301
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. margins r1, post

Adjusted predictions                                       Number of obs = 304
Model VCE: OIM

1._predict: Pr(r2==1), predict(pr outcome(1))
2._predict: Pr(r2==2), predict(pr outcome(2))
3._predict: Pr(r2==3), predict(pr outcome(3))
4._predict: Pr(r2==4), predict(pr outcome(4))

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 _predict#r1 |
       1#VL  |   .5774602    .062852     9.19   0.000     .4542724    .7006479
       1#SL  |   .1260196   .0349213     3.61   0.000     .0575751    .1944642
      1#NVL  |   .0545246   .0187742     2.90   0.004     .0177279    .0913213
     1#NAAL  |   .0003413   .0002841     1.20   0.230    -.0002156    .0008981
       2#VL  |   .2787612   .0418017     6.67   0.000     .1968313    .3606911
       2#SL  |   .2647495   .0390338     6.78   0.000     .1882447    .3412544
      2#NVL  |   .1768322   .0310688     5.69   0.000     .1159385    .2377259
     2#NAAL  |   .0053877   .0031116     1.73   0.083    -.0007109    .0114862
       3#VL  |   .1283549   .0344173     3.73   0.000     .0608983    .1958115
       3#SL  |   .4026165   .0372704    10.80   0.000     .3295678    .4756651
      3#NVL  |   .4096511   .0372963    10.98   0.000     .3365516    .4827505
     3#NAAL  |   .0702175   .0229076     3.07   0.002     .0253195    .1151156
       4#VL  |   .0154237   .0074265     2.08   0.038     .0008681    .0299793
       4#SL  |   .2066144   .0450394     4.59   0.000     .1183387    .2948901
      4#NVL  |   .3589921   .0488373     7.35   0.000     .2632727    .4547116
     4#NAAL  |   .9240536   .0256836    35.98   0.000     .8737146    .9743925
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. marginsplot, allxlabels ylab(#10) name("oprobit", replace) xtitle("Initial Response", size(medsmall)) ///
> plot(, label("VL" "SL" "NVL" "NAAL")) legend(title("Followup Response", size(medsmall))) ///
> title("Estimated Probabilities of Each Comfort Category by Initial Response, With 95% CIs", size(medsmall))

Variables that uniquely identify margins: r1 _outcome
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your help!